# pthread mutex lock does not work correctly

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I have a piece of code which I have using pthread_mutex_t to protect critical section but it doesn't work and when one thread lock the mutex another thread could access the critical section how ever the first thread has not unlocked the mutex.
Here is my code:

```cpp
#include "Eventloop.h"
#include <iostream>

pthread_t Eventloop::loopThread;
std::list<Event *> Eventloop::eventList;
pthread_mutex_t Eventloop::mutex;
Eventloop * Eventloop::eventloop = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t Eventloop::suspendMutex;
pthread_cond_t Eventloop::resumeCond;

void *checkEvents(void *args)
{
    while (1) {
        std::list<Event *>::iterator it;
        /* If event list is empty release control of processor 
        ** The thread is moved to the end of the queue
        */
       pthread_mutex_lock(&Eventloop::mutex);
       std::cout << "checkEvents lock eventloop mutex. \n";
        if (Eventloop::eventList.empty()) {
        }
        else {
            for(it = Eventloop::eventList.begin() ; it != Eventloop::eventList.end() ; it++) {
                (*it)->check();
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Eventloop::mutex);
        std::cout << "checkEvents unlock eventloop mutex. \n";
    }
}

/* Event loop constructor to create and detach the event thread */
Eventloop::Eventloop()
{
    pthread_create(&Eventloop::loopThread, NULL, &checkEvents, NULL);
    pthread_detach(Eventloop::loopThread);
}

void Eventloop::init()
{
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Eventloop mutex init succeed. \n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Eventloop mutex init failed. \n";
    }
    getInstance();
}

/* Instantiate the event loop.
** Event loop use singleton design pattern to ensure just only one object is instantiated
 */
Eventloop *Eventloop::getInstance()
{
    if(eventloop == NULL)
        eventloop = new Eventloop();
    return eventloop;
}

/* append() method to append events */
EventloopErr_t Eventloop::append(Event **event)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    std::list<Event *>::iterator it;
    for(it = eventList.begin() ; it != eventList.end() ; it++) {
        if((*it) == *event) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return EVL_ERR_EVENT_EXISTS;
        }
    }
    if (eventList.empty())
        resumeThread();
        std::cout << "Event in append method= " << *event << "\n";
    eventList.push_back(*event);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return EVL_ERR_OK;
}

/* remove() method to remove events */
void Eventloop::remove(Event **event)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    std::cout << "Eventloop::remove lock eventloop mutex. \n";
    std::list<Event *>::iterator it;
    for(it = eventList.begin() ; it != eventList.end() ; it++) {
        std::cout << "event = " << (*it) << "\n";
        if((*it) == *event) {
            delete eventList.back();
            eventList.remove(*event);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    std::cout << "Eventloop::remove unlock eventloop mutex. \n";
}
```

I would expect **Eventloop::remove(Event **event)** function can't enter into critical section when it is locked by thread but it doesn't.
here's the logs:

checkEvents lock eventloop mutex. **<-- this line mutex is locked.**
Eventloop::remove lock eventloop mutex. **<-- also in this line mutexis locked again.**
checkEvents unlock eventloop mutex.

in my main() :

```cpp
#include "Eventloop.h"
#include "Timer/Timer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

class TestTimerTask : public TimerTask
{
    public:
    void runTimerTask() {
        std::cout << "Timer is running \n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Eventloop::init();
    TestTimerTask timerTask;
    {
        
        Timer timer(&timerTask);
        timer.start(1000);
        usleep(1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    
}
```

Timer.h:

```cpp
#include <signal.h>
#include <Eventloop.h>

/*
** each client which wants to use timer must inherit a class form TimerTask 
** and implement runTimerTask() method
*/
class TimerTask
{
    public:
    virtual void runTimerTask() = 0;
};

class Timer
{
    private:
    uint16_t  durMs;
    TimerTask *timerTask;
    static long long getTimeMs();
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    long long startTime;
    sig_atomic_t stopFlag;
    Event *timerEvent;

    /*
    ** TimerEvent inherits form Event class and implement check interface
    ** Check interface execute timer handle() method
    */

    class TimerEvent : public Event 
    {
        private:
        Timer *timer;

        public:
        TimerEvent(Timer *t) {
            timer = t;
        }
        ~TimerEvent() {
            std::cout << "timer event destructor \n";
        }
        void check() {
            timer->handle();
        }
    };

    public:
    explicit Timer(TimerTask *_timerTask);
    ~Timer();
    void handle();
    void start(uint16_t ms);
    void stop();
};
```

Timer.cpp

```cpp
#include "Timer.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

/* 
** Timer constructor create a instantiate a TimerEvent class which inherit Event class 
** then append it to event loop as an event 
*/
Timer::Timer(TimerTask *_timerTask)
{
    timerEvent = new TimerEvent(this);
    Eventloop::append(&timerEvent);
    std::cout << "Event in Timer Constructor= " << timerEvent << "\n";
    timerTask = _timerTask;
    stopFlag = false;
}

/* 
** Timer destructor remove timer event from event loop
*/
Timer::~Timer()
{
    std::cout << "Timer destructor start\n";
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    Eventloop::remove(&timerEvent);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    std::cout << "Timer destructor end \n";
}

void Timer::start(uint16_t ms)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    durMs = ms;
    startTime = getTimeMs();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    stopFlag = false;
}

void Timer::stop()
{
    stopFlag = true;
}

long long Timer::getTimeMs()
{
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
}

/* 
** Handle method continuously check timer objects time out
*/
void Timer::handle()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (!stopFlag) {
        if (getTimeMs() - startTime >= durMs) {
            timerTask->runTimerTask();
            startTime = getTimeMs();
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `remove` is called. I'm betting it's called by the same thread that already has the lock. If so, `remove`'s `lock` will return `EDEADLK` instead of blocking. (It it did block, it would deadlock.) Check the value returned by your locking attempts to confirm.

Comment: in fact remove is called by main thread. which is not same with this thread here

Comment: Check the value returned by your locking attempts anyway. You claim it's failing, and that will tell you why. (`if ( ( errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) ) ) { ... }`)

Comment: I added where i called remove function

Comment: I checked the errno and its value is 60

Comment: That's ENOSTR Device not a stream on Linux. huh?

Comment: If `pthread_mutex_lock()` is failing then that explains the proximal issue right there.  I'm not immediately sure why it fails, but when it does fail, *of course* that call cannot be relied upon to provide the wanted mutual exclusion behavior.  This sort of thing is why it is important to check the return values of your function calls.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're doing here.  `EventLoop` appears to be designed as a singleton, and in particular, you appear to have a static member `Eventloop::eventloop` that will point to the singleton instance.  But in that case, why all the *other* static member variables?  Shouldn't those be instance variables (of the singleton instance)?